# How do I convert result from opening gzip file to string

Tags: node.js, request, gzip

```
 var request = require('request')
  request(
    { method: 'GET'
    , uri: 'http://www.examplewebsite.com'
    , gzip: true
    }
  , function (error, response, body) {
      console.log(body); //I am trying print body here
      console.log(response.body); // //I am trying print body here too
    }
  )
```

All I received is just `�V*.I,)-V�*)*M�QJI,IT��V��,.���%�E��)JV�����d��$1`
If I try to use JSON.stringify(body), the result is:

```
\u001f�\b\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0003�V*.I,)-V�*)*M�QJI,IT��V��,.\u0001��\u0019�\u0005%�E��)JV�����\u0000d��$1\u0000\u0000\u0000
```

All I want is to see the plain string. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect that setting `gzip : true` would decompress the response body automatically, but perhaps the server doesn't set the correct `Content-Encoding` header.

In that case, you can try this:

```
const zlib    = require('zlib');
const request = require('request');

request({
  method   : 'GET',
  uri      : 'http://www.examplewebsite.com',
  gzip     : true,
  encoding : null,
}, function (error, response, body) {
  let decompressed = zlib.gunzipSync(body).toString();
  ...
})
```